# Split a flux into two fluxes - head and tail

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to split a flux into two fluxes where the first one has the first item of the original flux and the second one will takes the rest of items.

After applying a custom transformation `myLogic` on each flux I want to combine them into one flux preserving the order of the original flux.

Example:

S: student
S': student after applying `myLogic`

Emitted flux:            `s1 -> s2 -> s3 -> s4`
The first splited flux:  `s1' => myLogic`
The second splited flux: `s2' -> s3' -> s4' => myLogic`
The combined flux:       `s1' -> s2' -> s3' -> s4'`

Comment: Maybe you just need a `LinkedList` ?

Comment: @suliman Please, accept an answer you find the most helpful for the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to use standard `Flux` methods `take` and `skip` to seprate head and tail  elements. Calling `cache` before that is also useful to avoid subscription duplication.

```
class Util {

  static <T, V> Flux<V> dualTransform(
    Flux<T> originalFlux,
    int cutpointIndex,
    Function<T, V> transformHead,
    Function<T, V> transformTail
  ) {
    var cached = originalFlux.cache();
    var head = cached.take(cutpointIndex).map(transformHead);
    var tail = cached.skip(cutpointIndex).map(transformTail);

    return Flux.concat(head, tail);
  }

  static void test() {
    var sample = Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d");

    var result = dualTransform(
                   sample,
                   1, 
                   x -> "{" + x.toUpperCase() + "}", 
                   x -> "(" + x + ")"
                 );

    result.doOnNext(System.out::print).subscribe();

    // prints: {A}(b)(c)(d)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two separate `Flux` objects and then merging them, you can just zip your original `Flux` with another `Flux<Boolean>` that's only ever `true` on the first element.

You can then do your processing conditionally as you please in a normal `map()` call without having to merge separate publishers later on:

```
Flux<String> values = Flux.just("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G");

Flux.zip(Flux.concat(Flux.just(true), Flux.just(false).repeat()), values)
        .map(x -> x.getT1() ? "_"+x.getT2().toUpperCase()+"_" : x.getT2().toLowerCase())
        .subscribe(System.out::print);    // prints "_A_bcdefg"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a more simple solution to your problem. You don't need to split and merge the events from publisher. You can make use of `index()`. It keeps information about the order in which events are published.

```
Flux<String> values = Flux.just("s1", "s2", "s3");
values.index((i, v) -> {
  if (i == 0) {
    return v.toUpperCase();
  } else {
    return v.toLowerCase();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky way to do this:

```
boolean a[] = new boolean[]{false};  //use an array as you cannot use non-final variables inside lambdas

    originalFlux
        .flatMap(a -> {
            if(!a[0]) {
                a[0] = true;
                return runLogicForFirst(a);
            } else {
                return runLogicForRest(a);
            }
        })
```