# Split a Flux into a Mono head and Flux tail

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

I want to split a `Flux` into two parts: A `Mono` for the 1st element (the head), and a `Flux` for everything else (the tail).
The base `Flux` should not be re-subscribed to in the course of this process.

**Example of what DOESN'T work:**

```java
final Flux<Integer> baseFlux = Flux.range(0, 3).log();
final Mono<Integer> head = baseFlux.next();
final Flux<Integer> tail = baseFlux.skip(1L);
assertThat(head.block()).isEqualTo(0);
assertThat(tail.collectList().block()).isEqualTo(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
```

The log for this looks something like the following, and as you can see, the base Flux will be re-subscribed to twice:

```
[main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers$LoggerFactory - Using Slf4j logging framework
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxRange.RangeSubscription)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | request(unbounded)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(0)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | cancel()
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxRange.RangeSubscription)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | request(unbounded)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(0)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(1)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onNext(2)
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | onComplete()
[main] INFO reactor.Flux.Range.1 - | request(1)
```

My actual case is that my base `Flux` contains the lines of a CSV file, with the first line being the header of the file, which is needed to parse all subsequent lines. The base `Flux` can only be subscribed to once, as it is based on an `InputStream`

The only somewhat related resource I found for this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58696866/1296709), but I found this to be somewhat unfitting for my needs.

Comment: See `Flux.switchOnFirst()` and you probably right doing that `skip(1)` to avoid the first element from the tail.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a suggestion offered in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544189/split-a-flux-into-a-mono-head-and-flux-tail#comment114128021_64544189), I was able to devise the following solution:

```java
final Flux<Integer> baseFlux = Flux.range(0, 3).log();
final Flux<? extends Tuple2<? extends Integer, Integer>> zipped = baseFlux
    .switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> (signal.hasValue()
        ? Flux.zip(Flux.just(signal.get()).repeat(), flux.skip(1L))
        : Flux.empty()));
final List<? extends Tuple2<? extends Integer, Integer>> list = zipped.collectList().block();
assertThat(list.stream().map(Tuple2::getT1)).isEqualTo(Arrays.asList(0, 0));
assertThat(list.stream().map(Tuple2::getT2)).isEqualTo(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
```

It transforms the base `Flux` after the 1st element, by zipping this element repeated with the tail of the original flux. And it only subscribes to the `baseFlux` once.

I'm not sure this is the best solution, as it will create a lot of `Tuple2` objects which will be GC'd eventually, compared to a solution which would have a stateful ("hot") flux based on the `baseFlux`, which keeps the original subscription alive.

Comment: An option without `.zip` and `Tuple2`s would likely require the creation of a custom `FluxProcessor`. Since my `baseFlux` is a "cold" flux, this `FluxProcessor` could subscribe to the `baseFlux` on another thread, and suspend it after the 1st element has been pushed. The thread can be resumed as soon as there is another subscriber to the `FluxProcessor`, which all remaining elements can be pushed to. However, this kind of blocking likely goes against the core principles of reactor. Alternatively a `ConnectableFlux` might be the way to go.

Comment: if you can declare the processing of `tail` that uses the `header` within the `switchOnFirst`, I guess one option would be to capture the csv header from `firstSignal` in a variable local to the lambda, then return `flux.skip(1L).flatMap(v -> process(v, csvHeader))`